# Fraction calculator adding

Tags: java, calculator

Hi I'm new to java and am working on a Fraction calculator and I am unable to figure out how to get the calculator to reduce simple fractions and add mixed fractions.
Example:
Reduction: 1/2 + -5/6 = -1/3
Mixed Fractions: 4_15/16 + -3_11/16 = 1_1/4
Edit: For mixed fractions, I tried to subtract the numerator from the denominator for num>den to get the whole and the remainder and return it and print but it's not printing out anything.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fraction {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter an Expression or quit:");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String text = input.nextLine();
    while (!text.equals("quit")){
    String frac1 = text.substring(0,text.indexOf(" "));
    String oper = text.substring((text.indexOf(" "))+1,(text.indexOf(" "))+2);
    String frac2 = text.substring((text.indexOf(" "))+3);
    int fn1 = num(frac1); //frac1 numerator
    int fd1 = den(frac1); //frac1 denominator
    int fn2 = num(frac2); //frac2 numerator
    int fd2 = den(frac2); //frac2 denominator
    if (oper.equals("+")){
        int sumfinalnum = add(fn1, fd1, fn2, fd2);
        if (fd1 == 1 && fd2 == 1){
            System.out.println(sumfinalnum);
            }
        else if ((fn1 + fn2)==0){
            System.out.println("0");
        }
        else if (fd1 == fd2){
            if (sumfinalnum>fd1){
                    System.out.println(extractWholePart(sumfinalnum,fd1)+"_"+extractNumPart(sumfinalnum,fd1)+"/"+fd1);
            }
            else{
        System.out.println(sumfinalnum+"/"+fd1);
        }
        }
        else if (!(fd1 == fd2)){
        System.out.println(sumfinalnum+"/"+(fd1*fd2));
        }
        System.out.println("Enter an Expression or quit:");
        text = input.nextLine();
        }
    }
    }

public static int num(String input){
    if (input.contains("_")){ //mixed to improper
        String a = input.substring(0,input.indexOf("_"));
        String b = input.substring((input.indexOf("_"))+1,input.indexOf("/"));
        String c = input.substring((input.indexOf("/"))+1);
        int a1 = Integer.parseInt(a);
        int b1 = Integer.parseInt(b);
        int c1 = Integer.parseInt(c);
        int d = a1*c1;
        int e = d+b1;
        return e;           
    }
    else if (!input.contains("/")){
        int input1 = Integer.parseInt(input);
        return input1;
    }
    else {
    String strnum1 = input.substring(0,input.indexOf("/"));
    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(strnum1);
    return num1;
    }
}
public static int den(String input){
    if(!input.contains("/")) {     //whole
        return 1;
    }
    String strnum2 = input.substring((input.indexOf("/"))+1);
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(strnum2);
    return num2;

}

public static int add(int fn1,int fd1,int fn2,int fd2){
    if (fd1 == fd2){ //matching denominator
        int numadd = fn1 + fn2;
        return numadd;
    }
    else if (fd1 == 1 && fd2 == 1){ //whole numbers no denom
        int sum = fn1 + fn2;
        return sum;
    }
    else if (!(fd1 == fd2)){ //different denominator***
        int dencomadd = fd1*fd2;
        int gcd1 = dencomadd/fd1;
        int gcd2 = dencomadd/fd2;
        int comf1num = fn1*gcd1;
        int comf2num = fn2*gcd2;
        int total = comf1num+comf2num;
        return total;
    }
    else{
        return 0;

    }


}
public static int extractWholePart(int finalnum, int finalden){
    int whole = 0;
    while (finalnum > finalden){
        whole++;
    }
    return whole;
}
public static int extractNumPart(int finalnum, int finalden){
    while (finalnum > finalden){
        finalnum -= finalden;
    }
    return finalnum;
}
}
```

Comment: To reduce a fraction: if the result is A/B, then find G = the greatest common divisor of `Math.abs(A)` and B.  Then reduce the fraction by dividing both A and B by G.  So if A=-4 and B=12, G will be 4, and then you'll divide both A and B by 4 to get -1/3.  If you don't know how to find the greatest common divisor, look up "Euclid's algorithm" in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with - It's java, don't be afraid to use bigger variable names. `fn1` could very well be called `fraction1Numerator`.

Next, have a single method to do what it's designed to do. Having an `add` method that needs four else-ifs in `main` is not a really good idea.

Creating an object `Fraction` that would have member variables `numerator` and `denominator` would allow your `add` function to return the entire answer. After all you have the code to add mixed fractions that looks good.

```
class Fraction{
    public int whole;
    public int numerator;
    public int denominator;
}
```

I also added "whole" to indicate whole part after simplification. `add` function would than have signature

```
public static Fraction add(Fraction fraction1, Fraction fraction2) ...
```

Extracting whole numbers is simple - subtract denominator from numerator until you can't do that anymore.

```
public void extractWholePart(Fraction fraction){
    int whole = 0;
    while (fraction.numerator > fraction.denominator){
        whole++;
        fraction.numerator -= fraction.denominator;
    }
    fraction.whole = whole;
}
```

simplification on the other hand is just dividing both nominator and denominator by the greatest common divisor - algorythm for calculating that is easily findable on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
float mixedToDecimal(String data)
// data would be like this "1 5/8";
String[] parts = data.split(" ");
if(!(parts.lenght > 0)) // this mean that if data is NOT mixedfraction then just return -1
   return -1;
float value = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
if (parts.length > 1) {
    // has fractional part
    parts = parts[1].split("/");
    float numerator = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    float denominator = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    value += numerator / denominator;
}
// value contains 1.625
return value;
```

Comment: I'm having difficulty returning it in a fraction form and if it includes a whole number there needs to be an underscore.